# Upload Multiple files using multipart/form-data in salesforce apex

Tags: file, salesforce, multipartform-data, apex

I am trying to upload multiple files to an endpoint using multipart/form-data but only one file goes through. I am utilizing the HttpFormBuilder class from salesforce to build the http request.

```
body += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
        for (FileObject file : sample.files) {
            
            //******This was the boundary I was missing****
            body += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBlobBodyParameter('file[]', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file.fileData), file.fileName);
            
            // body += WriteBoundary(EndingType.CrLf);
           
        }
body += WriteBoundary(EndingType.CrLf);       
        Blob bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body);
```

Also tried combining the files using

```
body += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
        for (FileObject file : sample.files) {
         
           
            combinedDataAsHex =  combinedDataAsHex + EncodingUtil.convertToHex(file.fileData);
            System.debug('file===>'+EncodingUtil.convertToHex(file.fileData));
        }    
        Blob combineBlob = combinedDataAsHex != null ? EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(combinedDataAsHex) : null;

        body += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBlobBodyParameter('file[]', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(combineBlob) , 'fgrger.pdf');
```

Only one file goes through in both the case. Any help will be much appreciated!